# Cygwin mysqldump complete-insert

Tags: cygwin, mysql

I am using actual cygwin version and have installed mysql package 5.5.21. When using mysqldump i have the problem that the insert statement is in one line. i have already tried the following statements but it seems that they do not take any effect on the output.

```
mysqldump --opt --extended-insert --complete-insert ....
mysqldump -c ...
```

Does anyone have an idea how i can force mysqldump to create an insert for each data row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--extended-insert` is what causes multiple rows on each line. It's also part of `--opt`.

Try adding `--skip-extended-insert`.